# c# connection string change due to database move

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string

We are moving database from one server to another. There are many connection strings of applications that needs to changed due to this. Is there any generic way where we can keep the connection string so that if we move the database again then this issue doesn't arise??

Comment: put the connection string in some sort of central location.  There are dozens of ways to do that I imagine.

Comment: Configure a fixed dns name for your database machine. If your db machine changes simply change the dns entry.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Has all kinds of examples, especially one using external Configuration files. You can point your applications to this file

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for response.. @Ralf could you please explain a little bit as to how will I implement this. If I just change the dns entry then I owuldn't have to touch my config files for all the apps???

Comment: If the servername in the connectionsstrings already maps to a/the name in the dns record no. You would simply change the ip address of that dns record to the one of the new machine. That works as long as you don't have to change more in the connectionstring like username/password, port etc. But if you distributing certain credentials with your connectionstring to your user then you already have other mayor problems you should fix first and in the process of fixing that centralising the connectionstring and getting them out of the grip of users would be just a detail.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many ways to resolve this problem.

Ultimately what it sounds like you want to do is centralize your database connection strings in such a way that a database migration is (mostly) transparent to your application.  I can think of a few options here:

1. Use a "control database" that houses your connection strings and configurations.  If you migrate to a new database server, you only have to update a single connection string in your application, and perform data updates for everything else.  This is what I personally use.
2. Use a central XML configuration file that is parsed on application startup.
3. Use SQL Server Aliases and/or add additional IPs to the machine that you can migrate between servers.  This way when you move to a new database server you can still bring along the existing aliases/IPs to that server (unless they need to run in parallel of course) and theoretically not need to update anything in your code, provided that you've referenced the appropriate aliases.  See here for more info: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56642/how-to-create-a-server-alias-in-sql-server-2012

Over here we ultimately went with option 1 because that gave us more flexibility and reliability than an XML configuration file (#2) and required less configuration and special cases to be documented with our DBAs, since we have no ownership of any database servers outside of our DEV environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have the connection string in an xml file and read the xml file and get the connection string from it. You only need to change the connection string in the xml file and not in the published code. By the way you can have multiple connection strings for Debug and Release modes and make your application choose it.

Answer (score 0):

You could store them in a database. ^_^

Jokes aside, I do not have experience with this myself, but using an Alias sound like it might suit you best:
http://blog.idera.com/sharepoint/performance-webcasts/plan-your-sharepoint-farm-right-with-a-sql-server-alias/

Answer (score 0):

First, you can store your connection strings in external file (custom storage or .config file) - so you will be able to change them without recompiling the code.
Second, you can use domain name instead of IP address
  And third, you can store your connection strings in parts and build them in runtime by ConnectionStringBuilder - so you can change only server part.